# unable to export MaterialModule from shared.module.ts on Build time

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material2, angular2-modules

It's working on **`ng serve`** but giving  error as follow

> ```
> ERROR in Unexpected value 'MaterialModule in E:/Code/employee-web/node_modules/@angular/material/typings/index.d.ts'
> ```
>
> impor
>       ted by the module 'SharedModule in E:/Code/employee-web/src/app/shared/shared.module.ts'. Please add a
>   @NgModule annotatio
>       n.
>       ERROR in ./src/main.ts
>       Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './$$_gendir/app/app.module.ngfactory' in 'E:\Code\employee-web\src'
>       resolve './$$_gendir/app/app.module.ngfactory' in 'E:\Code\employee-web\src'
>         using description file: E:\Code\employee-web\package.json (relative path: ./src)
>           Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
>         after using description file: E:\Code\employee-web\package.json (relative path: ./src)
>           using description file: E:\Code\employee-web\package.json (relative path: ./src/$$_gendir/app/app.module.ngfactory)
>             no extension
>               Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
>               E:\Code\employee-web\src\$$_gendir\app\app.module.ngfactory doesn't
>   exist
>             .ts
>               Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
>               E:\Code\employee-web\src\$$_gendir\app\app.module.ngfactory.ts doesn't
>   exist
>             .js
>               Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
>               E:\Code\employee-web\src\$$_gendir\app\app.module.ngfactory.js doesn't
>   exist
>             as directory
>               E:\Code\employee-web\src\$$_gendir\app\app.module.ngfactory doesn't
>   exist
>       [E:\Code\employee-web\src\$$_gendir\app\app.module.ngfactory]
>       [E:\Code\employee-web\src\$$_gendir\app\app.module.ngfactory.ts]
>       [E:\Code\employee-web\src\$$_gendir\app\app.module.ngfactory.js]
>       [E:\Code\employee-web\src\$$_gendir\app\app.module.ngfactory]
>        @ ./src/main.ts 3:0-74
>        @ multi ./src/main.ts

Can anyone look into this?

here is sharedModule

```
> @NgModule({
> 
>   declarations: [],   providers: [
>        ],   imports: [
>     HttpModule,
>     MaterialModule,
>        ],   exports: [
>     CommonModule,
>         //matrial MOdule
>     // MdTooltipModule,
>     // MdTabsModule,
>     // MdSlideToggleModule,
>     // MdIconModule,
>     // MdDialogModule,
>     // MdButtonModule,
>     // MdListModule,
>     // MdCardModule,
>     // MdToolbarModule,
>     // MdProgressSpinnerModule,
>     // MdProgressBarModule,
>     MaterialModule,
> 
> 
>       ] }) export class SharedModule { }
```

Comment: What version of material are you using? MaterialModule has been deprecated for a while now and it is now recommended to import the component modules individually.

Comment: @yoonjesung here is version "@angular/material": "^2.0.0-beta.8",

Comment: Looks like you're using one of the latest versions. Instead of importing/exporting MaterialModule, import/export the individual component modules instead.

Comment: You probably came from previous versions of angular/material then change it to beta 8. Try to delete the node_modules and do a npm install again

Comment: @yoonjesung  ist giving errors as follow ERROR in Unexpected value 'MdAutocompleteModule in E:/Code/employee-web/node_modules/@angular/material/typings/index.d.ts' imported by the module 'AppModule in E:/Co
de/employee-web/src/app/app.module.ts'. Please add a "@NgModule" annotation

Comment: Dont use materialmodule, import all the modules seperately

Comment: @Faisal I have updated all modules to the latest version. now everything is working fine

Answer (score 0):

You've likely done the following:

```
import {MaterialModule} from "@angular/material";

@NgModule({
   declarations: [],
   providers: [],
   imports: [
     HttpModule,
     MaterialModule,
   ],
   exports: [
     CommonModule,
     MaterialModule,
   ]
})
export class SharedModule {}
```

However, the MaterialModule has been deprecated for a while now (I don't remember what version exactly). It is now recommended you import the component modules individually: https://material.angular.io/guide/getting-started#step-3-import-the-component-modules

So change to something like the following:

```
// Import whatever components you intend to use in this shared module here
import {MdButtonModule, MdCheckboxModule} from '@angular/material';

@NgModule({
   ...
   imports: [MdButtonModule, MdCheckboxModule],
   exports: [MdButtonModule, MdCheckboxModule],
   ...
})
export class SharedModule {}
```

You can emulate the MaterialModule functionality (the kitchen sink) by importing every single component module available, and then exporting them from your shared module.

Comment: its giving errors as follow ERROR in Unexpected value 'MdAutocompleteModule in E:/Code/employee-web/node_modules/@angular/material/typings/‌​index.d.ts' imported by the module 'AppModule in E:/Co de/employee-web/src/app/app.module.ts'. Please add a "@NgModule" annotation –

Comment: Hmm strange. Did you also install @angular/cdk? I believe this is also a dependency, though not sure if that will affect anything.

Comment: yes this @angular/cdk  already installed  here is version   "@angular/animations": "^4.3.6",
    "@angular/cdk": "^2.0.0-beta.10",  "@angular/material": "^2.0.0-beta.10",

Answer (score -1):

I had the same error using MdDialog from MaterialModule. 
I just fixed it right now and it works.

I fixed it by specifying the particular material module I'm making use of in my app.

in my app.module.ts:

```
import { MdDialogModule } from '@angular/material';
imports: [
  MdDialogModule
]
```

in my component:

```
import { MdDialog } from '@angular/material'
import { AuthorizationComponent } from '../authorization/authorization.component'

export class HomeComponent implements OnInit { 
  constructor(private dialog: MdDialog){}

  ngOnInit() {
  this.dialog.afterAllClosed
    .subscribe( () => {
          //make changes 
      })
   }

    sign_up() {
      this.dialog.open(AuthorizationComponent)  //open component
    }

}
```