# Error : Please add a @NgModule annotation when using latest cli and material design

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-cli

I am importing material modules as follow in app module:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { SharedModule } from 'app/shared/shared.module';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import {
  MdTooltipModule,
  MdTabsModule,
  MdSlideToggleModule,
  MdIconModule,
  MdDialogModule,
  MdButtonModule,
  MdListModule,
  MdCardModule,
  MdToolbarModule,
  MdProgressSpinnerModule,
  MdProgressBarModule,
} from '@angular/material';


@NgModule({    
  declarations: [
    //..components
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
 MdTooltipModule,
  MdTabsModule,
  MdSlideToggleModule,
  MdIconModule,
  MdDialogModule,
  MdButtonModule,
  MdListModule,
  MdCardModule,
  MdToolbarModule,
  MdProgressSpinnerModule,
  MdProgressBarModule,

    SharedModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
  ],
  providers: [
    //..
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

This gives an error as follow for each Md Module. I also updated my Angular CLI and Material design. I also tried to import only MaterialModule, but it is deprecated.

> ERROR in Unexpected value 'MdTooltipModule in
>   E:/Code/employee-web/node_modules/@angular/material/typings/index.d.ts'
>   impor
>       ted by the module 'AppModule in E:/Code/employee-web/src/app/app.module.ts'. Please add a @NgModule
>   annotation.

How can I get rid of this?

Comment: have you imported ngModule?

Comment: @Vikhyath Maiya already imported as  import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

Comment: then post the exact code..Its not there in the code you posted

Comment: @VikhyathMaiya check post is edited

Comment: which version of angular are you using ? 2.x or 4.x?

Comment: import Material Module in your app.module.ts and add it to you imports block in app.module.ts

Comment: @VikhyathMaiya latest version its 4.x

Comment: @Iris_geek gives same error in case of importing MaterialModule

Answer (score 0):

you can still use

```
import {MaterialModule, MdNativeDateModule, MdButtonModule} from '@angular/material';
```

it may say `MaterialModule` is depricated but you dont get any errors. it works fine.

you can import all these extras modules in the shared module and add them in both imports and exports. and only import shared module in the app module and other feature modules. it works fine.

Comment: I have already done this. This gives me another error here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45993648/unable-to-export-materialmodule-from-shared-module-ts-on-build-time/45993818?noredirect=1#comment78949921_45993818 that's why I am importing directly to app module

Answer (score 0):

The error says there is not module called `MdTooltipModule` in the module you imported. That means in `'@angular/material'`, there is not `MdTooltipModule` module.

look into that folder inside your imported package atnode_modules folder and findout that package is part of all the `exported` modules

i think there might be a spelling mistake

one more think I see is you imported both `MdTooltipModule` and `MdToolbarModule`. make sure all youare importing exist inside the module